# d3.js moving average line chart (custom interpolation) with tool-tip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, linechart

I'm trying to add tooltip to my d3 js line chart. Most solutions seems to be based on circles being calculated to faciliate the tool-tip pop-ups. But that's unfortunently not working for me. My line chart has custom interpolation (based on a moving avarage function) and when I use my data to plot circles they end up all over the chart (which is expected; the line is an average, not the values themselves).

Do anyone have any pointers? Circles(the scatterplot-way) are perfectly ok but they have to be calculated with the same moving average as the line. I'm thinking some kind of function that give the coordinates for the moving-average function and then do the "normal" circley-stuff? But that means a duplicate function to the one I already have...

**Update3 - This doesn't work since I'm still obviously getting only the values, I think I got it now**

```
    // Add event listeners/handlers
svg.on('mouseover', function() {
  marker.style('display', 'inherit');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
  marker.style('display', 'none');
}).on('mousemove', function() {
   var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
   marker.attr('cx', mouse[0]);
  var datumVar = x.invert(mouse[0]),
    index = bisect(dataFilter, datumVar),
    startDatum = dataFilter[index - 1],
    endDatum = dataFilter[index],
    interpolate = d3.interpolateNumber(startDatum.Kvot, endDatum.Kvot),
    range = endDatum.datum - startDatum.datum,
    valueY = interpolate((datumVar % range) / range);
    console.log((valueY));
    marker.attr('cy', y(valueY));
});
```

Final code that creates an object containing the ma for my values:

```
var movingWindowAvg = function (arr, step) {  // Window size = step
    return arr.map(function (_, idx) { 
        var wnd = arr.slice(idx, idx + step);
        var result = d3.sum(wnd.map(function(d) { return d.Kvot; })) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(result)) { result = _; }
        var tmpDate = wnd[0].datum;
        return {Kvot: result, datum: tmpDate}; 
    });
};
```

The above code will give values for the first/last observations but those aren't n-moving average. So, almost there.

Comment: Make a fiddle, then we could do something on it.....

Comment: I could absolutely  do that. I was mostly out for a technique to do that, not that people should write the function for me. It will take a bit of time to set the fiddle up. In the meantime I think doing it this way should probably work: [link](http://zoopoetics.com/blog/?p=499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the position of your graph and the y axis index in the current frame displayed, you can relate those values to the mouse x and y coords from the mouseover event and calculate the value the line 'should' have at thatgiven point. Its not too accurate but it did the job for me.

This is a response for the technique if you want to see some code i could supply you with that later when im home.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it (almost). I have got a result but the lines are way off the mark most of the time. Probably a result of me having two lines I guess?